# Object Browser can't browse my own solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, objectbrowser

When I click on "My Solution" nothing comes up.
I have to use Custom Component Set.
When I try to add a project from the solution, it can't add it.
"The following components could not be browsed." ...projectnamehere
I have to browse for the .dll directly.
Also, not all the /// comments are showing up.

Comment: I have sad news for you, my friend: the object browser does not support F#.

Comment: Do you really want to see the underlying objects?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of Visual Studio; some features were cut due to time constraints:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/541514/object-browser-doesnt-open-an-f-dll

(As far as I know, it's still not working brilliantly in VS 2013).