# How to make an F# project work with the object browser

Tags: f#, objectbrowser

I have used the sample F# Empty WPF project and pulled in Paul Bett's ReactiveUI project via Nuget. Normally when I press (shift-f2) on an identifier in C#/VB.Net it takes me to the object browser so I can explore the interface of the object. However two problems.

- Initially ReactiveUI is not even available in the Object Browser. I had to go to the soution explorer and explicity click **view in object browser** on each reference and then they appeared in the object browser. Perhapps this is intended for F# projects??
- Second when I do have a symbol in my F# code, say an instance of ReactiveObject and do (shift-f2) I get an error **cannot navigate to definition. Source code not available**.

So my question is how can I solve the two above problems, the second being the most important.

Comment: The second issue has always been the behavior in VS2010 and VS2012 – I'd be surprised if there is a fix.

Comment: Given that the intellisense can show the correct type and XML doc it surprises me that its not a trivial fix to implement. I'll find it hard to convince the team to try f# if its hard to browse API in the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128131/object-browser-cant-browse-my-own-solution

Comment: Do you really want to see the underlying objects?

Comment: Let's say i want to browse the api from visual studio. For example I cursor over fst and press f12 it would be nice to see the doc for fst and then at a glance see all other functions associated with the list module. I think we are being pedantic here if we worry about it being called an "object" browser. Id call it a doc explorer.

Comment: These are limitations of Visual Studio, these kind of tasks are not very common in F#.   If you use MonoDevelop then a working object browser down to code is available.

Comment: :) tried getting mono develop working yesterday under osx. It's broken. I have another SO question open on that issue.

Comment: MonoDevelop is fine under OSX, are you talking about the F# binding?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I meant the f# binding.

Comment: Please raise any issues found under: 

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues?state=open  

Im trying to get a list of those that need to be resolved.